# MVC Localization of Default Model Binder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, globalization, resx

I am currently trying to figure out how to localize the error messages generated by MVC. Let me use the default model binder as an example, so I can explain the problem.

Assuming I have a form, where a user enters thier age. The user then enters "ten" in to the form, but instead of getting the expected error of

> "Age must be beween 18 and 25."

the message

> "The value 'ten' is not valid for Age."

is displayed.

The entity's age property is defined below:

```
    [Range(18, 25, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Errors), 
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Age", ErrorMessage = "Range_ErrorMessage")]    
    public int Age { get; set; }
```

After some digging, I notice that this error text comes from the `System.Web.Mvc.Resources.DefaultModelBinder_ValueInvalid` in the `MvcResources.resx` file.

Now, how can create localized versions of this file?

As A solution, for example, should I download MVC source and add `MvcResources.en_GB.resx`, `MvcResources.fr_FR.resx`, `MvcResources.es_ES.resx` and `MvcResources.de_DE.resx`, and then compile my own version of `MVC.dll`?

But I don't like this idea. Any one else know a better way?

Comment: A good blog about this is also here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://forums.asp.net/p/1512140/3608427.aspx, scroll down to Brad Wilson's reply near the bottom of that page (Sat, Jan 09 2010, 3:20 PM).  There are static properties on the DefaultModelBinder that you can set to localize the generic error messages.

The reason a generic error message is used instead of your [Range] message is that [Range] provides a *validation* error message, but this particular case is a *binding* error.  There's absolutely no way the framework can ever hope to convert the string "ten" to an Int32, so it can't even fire the [Range] validator.  This is what the "PropertyValueInvalid" key as mentioned in that forum controls.

Comment: Are the keys like "PropertyValueInvalid" officially documented somewhere ?

Answer (score 3):

In MVC3 do the following to change default messages:

1. add the App_GlobalResources folder to your ASP.NET site
2. add a new resource file, call it f.ex. MyResources.resx
3. add these keys

   - **PropertyValueRequired**: A value is required.
   - **PropertyValueInvalid**: The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.
4. in Application_Start of global.asax.cs add the line `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:  [**IDataErrorInfo**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx)  property

This article will help

- [**Validating with the IErrorDataInfo
  Interface (C#)**](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-37-cs.aspx)

Comment: For Validation, I use Fluent Validation. 

The problem here is not with validation, i think? The problem is that the MVC , or in this case, the default model binder is not localizing the error messages when it adds its own error message to the ModelState.Error dictionary. I want to use exactly the same behaviour as the default model binder provides, but I want to localize those error messages to other languages