# Validating datatypes... How/Where and custom error-string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I don't quite understand how MVC 2 is validating the datatypes, or how I could inject my own error-string/language.

Given a date-field in a View-Model:

```
 public DateTime Appointment { get; set; }
```

I would get the following error if I fill in an invalid date into the form: `The value '01.03.20111' is not valid for Appointment.`

I certainly know about DataAnnotations (DisplayName, Required etc.), but I don't know how the datatype-validation happens and where/how I could hook in?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 0):

That message comes from the ModelBinder. You can write your own custom model binders if you would like. Scott Hanselman has examples [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx).

Comment: Blimey... I really need to write a custom ModelBinder only to influence e.g. the language of this message? :-/ Seems like a flaw to me.

Comment: Seems that there is more about this [subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462690/mvc-localization-of-default-model-binder).