# asp.net MVC3 DefaultModelBinder error messages keys

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, resources, localization

There's a lot of question (and answer) here on stackoverflow and other site about translating the default error messages provided by the DefaultModelBinder, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462690/mvc-localization-of-default-model-binder) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646270/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-message-for-value-types/1374653#1374653).

All answers to these questions basically proprose to create a ressource (resx) file under App_GlobalResources and put a message for "PropertyValueInvalid".

That's fine, it *does* works, but there is *other* message also (ex. "The value xxx must be a number") and the big question is : where in hell can I have a **list of the messages key** used for model binding validation, with a description of the context they are used for so I can translate each of them ?

Answer (score 8):

When `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ResourceFileName";` is set in Application_Start method the DefaultModelBinder class uses other resource keys than defined in the resource file used by Asp.Net MVC.

While disassembling DefaultModelBinder there is a method GetUserResourceString that reads from the custom resource file. This functions is only called twice with these messages keys:

- **PropertyValueRequired** (A value is required.)
- **PropertyValueInvalid** (The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.)

These are the only messages that could be set for DefaultModelBinder in MVC3.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (MVC4). I added a ErrorMessages.resx in App_GlobalResources with my custom messsages, then set DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ErrorMessages"; ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "ErrorMessages"; in Global.asax Application_Start... and still shows standard messages. Keys I added: FieldMustBeDate, FieldMustBeNumeric (these work), PropertyValueInvalid, PropertyValueRequired (these two don't work)

Comment: I am using MVC4 and it works for me. Did you manually create a folder and name it App_Globalresources or did you right click the project and  add a ASP.NET Folder? Also, I did not add this: ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "ErrorMessages"