# Custom validation error message if user puts a non-numeric string in an int field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

This question has to have been asked before, but I think the search terms are too generic for me to find the answer I'm looking for, so I'll ask it again.

I have a model with an `int` property, and a range annotation.

If the user enters something other than an int, the validation message responds with `The value '<bad data>' is not valid for '<property name>'`... which is great, but I want to provide a bit more feedback, i.e., `Expecting an integer value in this field.`.

Since this validation fails before the other validators take a look, I don't know how (or if it's possible) to override the default validator message for this.

What are my options?

per request, I am posting the code, but there's not a lot to it:

```
[Range(0,65535, ErrorMessage="Port must be between 0 and 65535.")] 
public int Port { get; set; }
```

There is validation that occurs before it reaches the RangeAttribute.  I want to replace the default message with one of my own choosing.

Comment: Post actual code for int declaration including annotation.

Comment: Done, although I don't know how much good it will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using standard annotations, you should be able to override the error message with something like this:

```
[MyAnnotation(...., ErrorMessage = "My error message")]
public int myInt { get; set; }
```

Or do you actually want to append to the default error message instead of replacing it (not clear in question)?

Update: Misread -- suggest this as the answer: [How to change the ErrorMessage for int model validation in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587816/how-to-change-the-errormessage-for-int-model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc) or better yet [How to change 'data-val-number' message validation in MVC while it is generated by @Html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828297/how-to-change-data-val-number-message-validation-in-mvc-while-it-generate-by-he/6405298#6405298)

Comment: Ah! Misread -- I think you want this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587816/how-to-change-the-errormessage-for-int-model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: This is another option -- it actually has an accepted answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828297/how-to-change-data-val-number-message-validation-in-mvc-while-it-generate-by-he/6405298#6405298

Comment: Yeah that last one seemed to provide the answer I was looking for... but in such a way that I've decided I'll keep the default message.  Way too much work for something that should be simple.

Comment: You've probably caught it already but you can use `[Display(Name = "My nice name")]` in the case that your variable name doesn't look/read right in the error message. I am surprised too that it is that hard to change.

Answer (score 4):

You can also inherit IValidatableObject in your model class. You can write down your required logic in the Validate method. Please find sample code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Alok : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Display(Name = "Property1")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Property1 is required.")]
        public int Property1 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Property2")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Property2 is required.")]
        public int Property2 { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Property1 < Property2)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Property 1 can't be less than Property 2.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  The validation error is added to the model at mapping time which occurs before the "official" validation.

Answer (score 1):

read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260435/asp-net-mvc3-defaultmodelbinder-error-messages-keys). In the link that the OP suggest you will find the way to replace the deafult error string that use the framework, while in the answer you will find a linnk to the other resources in case you want to change all of them. Look also [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/3607981.aspx). Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah updating the resource file is about furthest from my mind; additionally, it does not seem to support branching due to different type conversion errors.

Comment: Guess you have to write your own extension like the answer you already find. Sorry