# Catch "FieldMustBeNumeric" before "PropertyValueInvalid" in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm in situation when I define a Resourses file to change default global messages like (follow tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866720/3555947):

```
FieldMustBeNumeric - {0} not a nummber.
PropertyValueInvalid - {1} is invalid.
```

and I declare a variable like:

```
public int number { get; set; }
```

When I input a string on the form, it always show the message of "PropertyValueInvalid", but I want to show the message of "FieldMustBeNumeric".

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Can you show more code?   How are you attempting to read the value on the form?  What is your exception handling?  Where are you setting the error messages?

Comment: I follow the tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10866720/3555947, I just submit data to server side and catch ModelState message.